# How to obtain the value of the result in a `node-mysql` query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am weighting a node.js application, the result I get from my mysql query is,

```
[ RowDataPacket { name: 'ubuntu' } ]
```

(Ubuntu is the only thing in the row)

What I would like to do is shorten my variable, "results" so that it equals ubuntu for example, or just every thing between the '', I am new to JS. I am using the standard way of querying the sql database, 
 It is being done as so:

```
   var mysql      = require('mysql');
   var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root', //just using root for my personal testing.
   password : 'root',
   database : 'Sonic'
   });

   connection.connect();

    var connect = connection.query( 'SELECT name FROM Sonic_url',      
       function(err,     fields, results, rows) {
    // if (results === input) {
    var sqldata = results.substring(1, 4);
    console.log(results);
    if (err) throw err;


   //  console.log('I belive we have found what you are after, is: ' +  input + ' ' + 'what you are after?');
   //}
    });
```

I would like to be able to do a basic IF with the variable input and a variable from the mysql query, so I can print to screen if the result was found or not.

Comment: What exactly produces the output `[ RowDataPacket { name: 'ubuntu' } ]`? You need to learn the basics about objects and arrays. Have a look at [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Comment: Did you try `console.log(results[0].name);`?

Comment: "weighting"? Did you mean *writing*? Or *weighing* (e.g., determining how "heavy" it is, perhaps in terms of data transfer...)?

Comment: No I haven't, I will now though.

Comment: Felix Kling, when I do console.log(results); it prints that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct signature for the [mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#performing-queries) query is:

```
connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
  // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
  // results will contain the results of the query
  // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)
});
```

What you want is to log the value of `name`. If your query produces one result, you can access this value from the first item in the `rows` array:

```
connection.query('SELECT name FROM Sonic_url', function(err, rows, fields) {
  console.log(rows[0].name);
});
```

Comment: Can I use the same method for 2 queries?